# Problem : add_footnotes with scale_down on KableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I´m already using add_footnote but when using both with kable_styling (latex_options = "scale_dwon), the scale down doesn´t work (i.e doesn´t go down the scale) indeed, it goes up.

```
kable(data_1,
  booktabs = T,
  caption = "My Caption",
  col.names = c("1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8"),
  format.args = list(big.mark = ","), 
  align = "lccccccc"
  ) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down") %>%
        row_spec(0, bold = T) %>% 
           column_spec(1, bold = T) %>% add_footnote("My calcs")
```

I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: Without a [sample of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or any way to see your output, it's unclear what you mean. You expect the table to shrink to fit within the page, but it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, when i´m using the option add_footnote without kable_styling, the shrink to fit within the page works perfect, nonetheless, once I start using add_footnote and kable_styling, it doesn´t shrink to fit anymore.

Sorry I can´t post a sample of my data because it is confidential. :(

Comment: See the link I posted. You can always create dummy data or use a commonly available dataset that replicates the issue